# Convert async lambda expression to delegate type System.Func<T>?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0, portable-class-library

I have an async method inside a portable class library with this signature:

```
private async Task<T> _Fetch<T>(Uri uri)
```

It fetches a resource that is cast back as a concrete type T.

I'm working with a 3rd party cache library ([Akavache](https://github.com/github/Akavache)) that requires a `Func<T>` as one of the parameters and have tried to do so in this manner:

```
await this.CacheProvider.GetOrCreateObject<T>(key,
    async () => await _Fetch<T>(uri), cacheExpiry);
```

This results in the error:

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type '`System.Func<T>`'. An async lambda expression may return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`, none of which are convertible to '`System.Func<T>`'.

I've tried various permutations of `Func<T>` assignment without any luck, the only way I can get the code to work is to make the `Func<T>` blocking:

```
await this.CacheProvider.GetOrCreateObject<T>(key, 
    () => _Fetch<T>(uri).Result, cacheExpiry);
```

which deadlocks my app.

Any pointers on where I'm going astray?

Comment: You're looking for `Func<T, Task>`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No can do. When someone expects a `Func<T> f` you can assume it will be invoked with something  like  `result = f()` - i.e., it does not know about async behavior. If you cheat it by using `.Result` like you have, it **will** deadlock on UI thread because it wants to schedule the code after `await` (in `_Fetch`) on the UI thread, but you have already blocked it with `.Result`.

Async lambda can be passed to `Action` since it has no return value - or to `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`.

Looking at your case, the `GetOrCreateObject` appears to be calling `GetOrFetchObject`. One of the `GetOrFetchObject` overloads accepts a `Func<Task<T>>`. You can try calling that method with your async lambda and see if it helps.

Comment: I would like to stress that if a method accepts an `Action` and you pass it an `async` lambda, then that's the wrong thing to do, most of the time.

Comment: @svick: Yes agree with you. Just like method which accepts `Func<T>`, method accepting an `Action` wont know about its async behavior. Async lambda which dont return any result would be ideally passed to `Func<Task>`. Its just that C# compiler allows it to be passed to `Action` because there is no return value.

Comment: Thanks YK1, I feel quite silly now - I had implemented an interface to abstract away the cache provider and missed the alternate method on the base library.

Answer (score 9):

[YK1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227923/263693) explains why you can't treat `Func<T>` as asynchronous.

To fix your problem, use `GetOrFetchObject` instead of `GetOrCreateObject`. The "create" methods assume a (synchronous) creation, while the "fetch" methods work with (asynchronous) retrieval.

```
await CacheProvider.GetOrFetchObject<T>(key, () => _Fetch<T>(uri), cacheExpiry)
```

I also removed the unnecessary `async`/`await` in your lambda expression. Since `_Fetch` already returns `Task<T>`, there's no need to create an `async` lambda whose sole purpose is to `await` that task.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this is exactly how I ended up solving the problem.