# How to hydrate a Dictionary with the results of async calls?

Tags: c#, async-await

Suppose I have code that looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> DoSomethingReturnString(int n) { ... }
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2 , 3};
```

Suppose that I want to create a dictionary that contains the result of calling `DoSomethingReturnString` for each number similar to this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = numbers.ToDictionary(n => n,
    n => DoSomethingReturnString(n));
```

That won't work because DoSomethingReturnString returns `Task<string>` rather than `string`.  The intellisense suggested that I try specifying my lambda expression to be async, but this didn't seem to fix the problem either.

Comment: `DoSomethingReturnString(n).Result`, but then it's blocking. If that's not what you are going for then you'd need async function that returns a `Task<Dictionary<int,string>>`

Comment: This is a great example of why "async all the way down" is a guiding principle when working with async code.

Comment: Is the consuming code asynchronous too?

Comment: Yes, the consuming code is asynchronous.

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17226284/1026459

Answer (score 20):

If you insist on doing it with linq, `Task.WhenAll` is the key to "hydrate" the dictionary:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2 , 3};

KeyValuePair<int, string>[] keyValArray = //using KeyValuePair<,> to avoid GC pressure
    await Task.WhenAll(numbers.Select(async p => 
        new KeyValuePair<int, string>(p, await DoSomethingReturnString(p))));

Dictionary<int, string> dict = keyValArray.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Comment: With C#7 you can use Tuples instead of KeyValuePair: var keyValTuples = await Task.WhenAll(numbers.Select(async p =>  (p, await DoSomethingReturnString(p))));

Answer (score 11):

LINQ methods do not support asynchronous actions (e.g., asynchronous value selectors), but you can create one yourself. Here is a reusable `ToDictionaryAsync` extension method that supports an asynchronous value selector:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static async Task<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> ToDictionaryAsync<TInput, TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TInput> enumerable,
        Func<TInput, TKey> syncKeySelector,
        Func<TInput, Task<TValue>> asyncValueSelector)
    {
        Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            var key = syncKeySelector(item);

            var value = await asyncValueSelector(item);

            dictionary.Add(key,value);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
private static async Task<Dictionary<int,string>>  DoIt()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    return await numbers.ToDictionaryAsync(
        x => x,
        x => DoSomethingReturnString(x));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is just a combination of @Yacoub's and @David's answers for an extension method which uses Task.WhenAll

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> ToDictionaryAsync<TInput, TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TInput> enumerable,
    Func<TInput, TKey> syncKeySelector,
    Func<TInput, Task<TValue>> asyncValueSelector) where TKey : notnull
{
    KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] keyValuePairs = await Task.WhenAll(
        enumerable.Select(async input => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(syncKeySelector(input), await asyncValueSelector(input)))
    );
    return keyValuePairs.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `ToDictionary`, you could also use the constructor: `return new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(keyValuePairs);` It might be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If calling from an asynchronous method, you can write a wrapper method that creates a new dictionary and builds a dictionary by iterating over each number, calling your `DoSomethingReturnString` in turn:

```
public async Task CallerAsync()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = await ConvertToDictionaryAsync(numbers);
}

public async Task<Dictionary<int, string>> ConvertToDictionaryAsync(int[] numbers)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        var n = numbers[i];
        dict[n] = await DoSomethingReturnString(n);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without using a loop?  Using a lambda expression seems cleaner to me.

Comment: The lambda will iterate internally as is.  The syntactic sugar of the lambda in your case is actually getting in the way of properly awaiting. It's certainly possible, but it may also hurt your readability.

Comment: In addition, a LINQ approach may also end up iterating twice depending on usage and structure...once to select and another time to create the dictionary.  This approach will always only iterate once.