# Use LINQ to fill Dictionary with async method

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, async-await

I am trying to fill in the `Dictionary<long, Data>` . Method `GetData` which returns data is async so I use following code to get the dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = entities
  .GroupBy(e => e.EntityId)
  .Select(e => e.First())
  .ToDictionary(e => e.EntityId, async entity => await GetData(entity));
```

Unfortunately myDictionary is of type `Dictionary<long, Task<Data>>`

How to fill in the using async lambda in ToDictionary?

Comment: The simplest, but arguably incorrect workaround is to use `GetData(entity).GetAwaiter().Result`, as this simply forces all the asynchronous operations to execute synchronously. But there is no support in either LINQ or PLINQ (that I know of) for properly constructing collections asynchronously.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: yeah, but I lose all the benefits of async/await

Comment: You need `.ToDictionaryAsync`, but such a method does not exist (except in EF, but then it's never a fully generic version). [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37796139/4137916), albeit with no really good answers.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var myDictionary = 
                (await Task.WhenAll(entities
                .GroupBy(e => e.EntityId)
                .Select(e => e.First())
                .Select(async e => new {e.EntityId, Data = await GetData(e)})))
                  .ToDictionary(e => e.EntityId, e => e.Data);
```

Comment: GetData returns Task<Data> so it returns Dictionary<long, Task<Data>>

Comment: And there I thought, this is section is for answers and not for questions. ;)

Comment: Wasn't Dictionary<long, Task<Data>> what was desired? Or did I missunderstand

Comment: @Servy The tasks are awaited:  `await Task.WhenAll(...`

Comment: @Servy "extremely terrible", come on...

Comment: @Magnus: thanks, will try this one and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @jabko87 You really shouldn't reward people for both posting incorrect answers, and just copying solutions from the duplicate into their own answer.

Comment: @Servy I did not copy from your duplicate, just wrote it. But if it is incorrect please let me know why.

Comment: @Magnus "Just remove the await?" which does nothing at all.

Comment: @Servy This is a community where we try to help each other the best we can. Being obnoxious does not help anyone.

Comment: @Magnus And how does posting an answer with an incorrect solution and duplicating a solution posted earlier helping anyone?  Also note this is a site to create a useful repository of knowledge, not a help desk.

Comment: @Servy I know you are an extremely good developer, I have read many of your answers. But you really should try to be a little bit more humble.