# C# await X and .Result not equivalent in ToDictionary()?

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to use `ToDictionary` on a bunch of `Task<MyObject>` (see below). This works ok if I use `TheTask.Result`, but not await

This works:

```
Dictionary<CarId, Task<Model>> allModelTasks = carIds.ToDictionary(cId =>cId, cId=> GetModelForCar(cId));                                  
await Task.WhenAll(allModelTasks.Values);
Dictionary<CarId, Model> allModels = allModelTasks.ToDictionary(mt => mt.Key, mt => mt.Value.Result);
```

But if I replace last row with

```
Dictionary<CarId, Model> allModels = allModelTasks.ToDictionary(mt => mt.Key, async mt => await mt.Value);
```

I get an error message that says "cant convert from `Dict<CarId, Task<Model>>` to `Dict<CarId, Model>`". 
As I see it, the rows should be equivalent.

(The recommendation [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197699/awaiting-multiple-tasks-with-different-results), seems to be to use await instead of `.Result`, even after *EDIT* `Task.WhenAll`)

Comment: Please pay attention to edits - my edit made generics visible with the correct syntax. Yours wiped that out and made them invisible in the first para, for instance.

Comment: How does `GetModelForCar` look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Given that the first code works, `Task<Model> GetModelForCar(CarId id)`.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [How to hydrate a Dictionary with the results of async calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796139/how-to-hydrate-a-dictionary-with-the-results-of-async-calls) It contains implementations of a `ToDictionaryAsync` method. These implementations `await` each value sequentially though, so it's not what you want. Which indicates why there is no such built-in method: it can be implemented in multiple ways with different behaviors.

Comment: "even after Task.WaitAll" - the advice is also: to avoid `WaitAll` :)

Comment: Ok... just went away for a few hours and had 7 answers and comments... Ill try to answer all. @ Pavel:see answer from CSerg. @ Theo: Thanks! It seems like what I want! @ Marc: Im not using WaitAll, I just happen to miswrite (for the 30th time :D), I meant WhenAll

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be ignoring that to be able to write `await` in that last line, you also had to add another `async`. Which means the `await` isn't "in" your current method - it's inside a new `async` lambda that, of course, being `async` returns a `Task`.

You can't use `await` inside a lambda here and expect not to still have a task to unwrap. Your first code is fine, and doesn't suffer any of the potential problems that accessing `.Result` can cause because the `Task`s are all known to already be complete.

---

You could create or copy some form of `ToDictionaryAsync` extension method into your class, something like:

```
public static class TaskResultExtensions
{
    public static async Task<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> ToDictionaryAsync<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, Task<TValue>>> source)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var kvp in source)
        {
            dict.Add(kvp.Key, await kvp.Value);
        }

        return dict;
    }
}
```

Which would then allow your final line to be

```
Dictionary<CarId, Model> allModels = await allModelTasks.ToDictionaryAsync();
```

instead.

Comment: Ok, yes. I get that .Result is ok bec of WhenAll(), but I wanted it to work with await, bec. (1) In my current project, my code might be copy-pasted and dont want to encurage .Result for blocking reaseon. (2) I might not be 100% sure What Stephen Cleary means in anwer (" I recommend using await because it's clearly correct, while Result can cause problems in other scenarios."). If those scenarios was without any await/WhenAll(). ... but mostly out of curiousity. To get to my point: Where am I supposed to put that *await*? Could you correct that last line for me?

Comment: @Cowborg - if there was a straightforward place to put an `await` in that last line, I'd have suggested it. If you really want to `await` then you can create a new Dictionary yourself and then iterate the contents of your first dictionary awaiting each value in turn before adding to the new dictionary. But I find that a "noisier" implementation.