# Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<bool, string, bool>'

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

I am getting an error with the following code.

```
public async Task<bool> FlushUrlAsync(Uri url, bool recursive, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    _serverPortsConfig.CacheServerPorts
        .Select(cacheServerPort => $"http://{url.Host}:{cacheServerPort}{url.AbsolutePath}")
        .Aggregate(true, (current, memoryCacheUrl) => current && await FlushUrlAsync(recursive, memoryCacheUrl)); //<--- produces the next error:
    // Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
    // 'Func<bool, string, bool>'. An async lambda expression may return 
    // void, Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to
    // 'Func<bool, string, bool>'.
 }
```

This method calls the following function

```
private async Task<bool> FlushUrlAsync(bool recursive, string memoryCacheUrl)
{
    return await someMagic(); //for clearity I removed the code.
}
```

It looks a lot like: [Convert async lambda expression to delegate type System.Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226284/convert-async-lambda-expression-to-delegate-type-system-funct), howevery, there solution won't /can't get it to work for me.

I had:

```
var result = true;
foreach (var cacheServerPort in _serverPortsConfig.CacheServerPorts)
{
    var memoryCacheUrl = $"http://{url.Host}:{cacheServerPort}{url.AbsolutePath}";
    result = result && await FlushUrlAsync(memoryCacheUrl, recursive);
}

return result;
```

Then resharper gave me the code that is provided, but just adding the async keyword doesn't work.

```
.Aggregate(true, async (current, memoryCacheUrl) => current && await FlushUrlAsync(recursive, memoryCacheUrl));
```

will give me the erorr: the return type of async method must be void, task or Task.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally use the `foreach` implementation, but answering the concrete question.

Without `async` the `Aggregate` overload used has the following signature:

```
bool Aggregate<bool, string>(bool seed, Func<bool, string, bool> func)
```

Note the `func` parameter - it's a method receiving `bool` and `string` returning a `bool`. The important part is that the type of the first argument is the same as the type of the result, as well as the type of `seed` parameter.

Since `async` lambda must return a `Task` derived object. You need a `bool` result, so let substitute it with `Task<bool>`:

```
Task<bool> Aggregate<bool, string>(Task<bool> seed, Func<Task<bool>, string, Task<bool>> func)
```

which leads to the following solution:

```
return await _serverPortsConfig.CacheServerPorts
    .Select(cacheServerPort => $"http://{url.Host}:{cacheServerPort}{url.AbsolutePath}")
    .Aggregate(Task.FromResult(true), async (current, memoryCacheUrl) => 
        await current && await FlushUrlAsync(recursive, memoryCacheUrl));
```

Comment: perfect! but i have to agree.... using the foreach makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use ContinueWith with TaskContinuationOptions,

```
 Func<Exception, bool> handlerFunc = (Exception ex) =>
            {

                 ex.HandleExceptionAsync().ContinueWith(async (result) => 
                 {
                    // all await operations can be called here
                 }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

                return true;
            };
```